# Hunspell integration error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hunspell, nhunspell

I have been trying to integrate the NHunspell spell checker API into a unity project that I am currently working on. I have been able to set it up correctly using the code:

```
void Start()
{
      using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("Assets/Dictionaries/en_GB-oed.aff", "Assets/Dictionaries/en_GB-oed.dic"))
      {
            bool correct = hunspell.Spell("Recommendation");
            Debug.Log("Recommendation is spelled " + (correct ? "correct" : "not     correct"));
      }
}
```

but when I press play, I get the following error:

[NHunspell Unity Error](http://puu.sh/aEaRG/96173f1001.png)

The files were downloaded from the Nhunspell website and are in the correct directory location:

[AFF/DIC File Location](http://puu.sh/aEb0u/694b6b4443.png)

I understand that the error is caused because it believes the aff file to be null but it isn't. I haven't been able to find anyone with the same problem online and other examples using NHunspell seem to work without any problems using the same code. wherever I put the files in the directory the same error occurs.

If anyone can help me with this, It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm the stack trace of your exception? From the posted code, it's unclear what's causing it.

Comment: This is what I recieved:
ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs:138)
NHunspell.MarshalHunspellDll.get_NativeDLLPath ()
NHunspell.MarshalHunspellDll.ReferenceNativeHunspellDll ()

Comment: That looks like a different error to what you think. It's not failing to find your dictionary; it's failing to properly load the Hunspell library. I don't know the library well, but it looks as though you need two DLLs - one managed, and one unmanaged. Do you have both of those in your project?

Comment: Oh ok, Thanks. I'm not sure as I installed Hunspell using the Nuget package Manager as it was suggested on the Hunspell website.(I don't use API's that are not Unity packages often so I may not understand everything) is there a easy way for me to check?

Comment: We (the NHunspell) developers will investigate in this issue. This is the post in our support forum: http://www.crawler-lib.net/boards/topic/6/having-implementation-issues

Comment: Did you find a soltution ? I have the same issue trying using it with Unity3D. I think it is a compatibility problem due to the fact Unity3D is using an old version of .Net through Mono.

Comment: Sadly I did not find a solution and had to write my own Spell checking system

Comment: Is there any update about this problem?